# c++ duplicate behavior in new class with different map

Tags: c++, design-patterns, stl

If I have two classes A and B defined as:

```
class A {
    map<int, int> mMap;
    vector<int> mVec;

    void method() {
      // do something with mMap and mVec 
    }
}

class B {
    map<int, double> mMap; // just an example of a map with a different signature

    ...
}
```

It is possible somehow to use everything A has in B but with the new map defined in B and without rewriting `method` ?

This is a simplified example of what I am trying to do: refactoring a big class with a new map.

Comment: Why not `template<typename T> class Foo { map<int, T> mMap; ... };`?

Comment: @ildjarn That "why not" can probably be expanded into an excellent answer :)

Comment: @ildjarn I cannot change class A. Work related stuff... :(

Comment: And also I tried to simplify the example. The difference between the maps is more complex than int-double.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : The OP's followup comments are exactly why I don't jump straight to an answer most of the time. :-]

Comment: In the case that you can't modify class A, there aren't any other besides cut-and-paste.  You can still follow ildjarn's idea to implement your class B as an instantiation of a template class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use

```
std::map<int, Y>
```

instead of

```
std::map<int, X>
```

with the same code, to replace `class A` with `class B`, then there probably exists a strong correlation between the types `X` and `Y`.

In this case, if you cannot use templates on `class A`, a possible workaround may be to define implicit type conversion operators for both `Y` and `X` to `X` and `Y` respectively.

```
class X {
    operator Y() {
        Y y;
        // Conversion logic
        return y;
    }
};
```

By doing so, you don't need to change the code of `method` as the insertion or access operations on the map will automatically call the implicit type conversion operators.

Warning note: the abuse of implicit conversion operators weakens the type safety checkings of the compiler that you may expect in other parts of the code (e.g.: wrong `Y` parameter passed to `f(X &x)`).

Comment: A problem here is that X is int and Y is double, both are primitive types.

Comment: @ApprenticeQueue I based on his comment ***The difference between the maps is more complex than int-double*** and thought `int` and `double` were just placeholders to explain the problem.

Comment: Even if we disregard primitive types, this answer is unsustainable and just asking for trouble.

Comment: @ApprenticeQueue this is what I can suggest given the constraints imposed by the OP. Better answers are welcome and everyone is allowed to post them. Feel free.